# "There is no row at position 0"?

Tags: database, vb.net

```
Private Sub BtnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
    Dim sql As String
    sql = " SELECT * FROM LoginDetails WHERE UsernameID = '" & TxtUsername.Text & "' AND Password = '" & TxtPassword.Text & "'"
    ds = db.sqlSelect(sql)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Username As String = ds.Tables("LoginDetails").Rows(i)("UsernameID")
    Dim Password As String = ds.Tables("LoginDetails").Rows(i)("Password")
    ''''''STUDENT LOGIN'''''''
    If TxtUsername.Text = "" And TxtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("No username and password entered!")
    ElseIf TxtUsername.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("No username entered!")
    ElseIf TxtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("No password entered!")
    End If
    Username = TxtUsername.Text.ToLower
    Password = TxtPassword.Text.ToLower
    If TxtUsername.Text.ToLower = Username And TxtPassword.Text = Password Then
        FrmMainMenu.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        FrmMainMenu.LblWelcome.Text = "Welcome " & ds.Tables("LoginDetails").Rows(i)("Student Name") & "!"
    ElseIf TxtUsername.Text.ToLower = Username And TxtPassword.Text <> Password Then
        MsgBox("Wrong password entered!")
    End If
    If TxtUsername.Text.ToLower <> Username And TxtPassword.Text <> Password Then
        MsgBox("Wrong password or username!")
    Else
    End If
    If Len(Username) <> 7 Then
        MsgBox("Username must be exactly 7 characters long and must be in the following format: 1XlXXXX")
    End If
    If Len(Password) < 6 And Len(Password) > 30 Then
        MsgBox("Password must be between 6 and 30 characters!")
    End If
```

When I type in the correct details for the form it works, but whenever I type in say a wrong password, it crashes!

Can anyone help me solve this?? I keep getting this error!!!

IndexOutofRangeException was unhandled

There is no row at position 0.

Pointing at the code: Dim Username As String = ds.Tables("LoginDetails").Rows(i)("UsernameID")

Here is the class that links the code to my database:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class clsDBConnector
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim dbProvider As String
Dim dbSource As String
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Sub connect()
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = E:\Computing\COMP4\Database.accdb "
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open()
End Sub
Function sqlSelect(ByVal sqlString As String)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlString, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "LoginDetails")


    Return ds
End Function
Sub reset()
    ds.Reset()
End Sub
Sub SQLinsert(ByVal sql) 'inserts data into database
    Dim da As New OleDbCommand(sql, Con)
    da.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
Function SQLupdate(ByVal sqlString As String)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlString, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "LoginDetails")
    Return ds

End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Im guessing that `Rows(i)` -- there is no row at 0 -- seems obvious, check the row first.

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcThKA9Sksq-4UEROvB_vroAVIhfXQBWDPoy58WxBvsqt8RlVlETwg

Answer (score 1):

The **first** thing you're doing wrong is storing plain-text passwords.  ***Never store plain-text passwords.***

The **second** thing is that you're *wide open* to SQL injection attack.  Use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953.aspx).  Otherwise you're allowing users to arbitrarily execute any code they'd like on your database.

The **third** thing is that you're assuming a returned value here:

```
sql = " SELECT * FROM LoginDetails WHERE UsernameID = '" & TxtUsername.Text & "' AND Password = '" & TxtPassword.Text & "'"
ds = db.sqlSelect(sql)
Dim i As Integer
Dim Username As String = ds.Tables("LoginDetails").Rows(i)("UsernameID")
Dim Password As String = ds.Tables("LoginDetails").Rows(i)("Password")
```

If that `SELECT` statement doesn't find any values, then `Rows(i)` (`i` is `0` in this case since that's the default for an `Integer`) doesn't exist.  You need to check the count of `Rows` before trying to access it.  In this case, logically, if `Rows.Count` is `0` then no match was found for the username/password combination, so the login fails.  Notify the user that the login has failed and stop executing anything else.

The **fourth** thing you're doing wrong is storing plain-text passwords.  [***Never store plain-text passwords.***](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Before you start using the dataset after the SQL call you should alway check to see if you received valid/any data back .   Call a DataSet check method like the one I included. If it returns false you know your SQL returned an empty DataSet. So you can display a message stating invalid login info..

```
bool IsEmpty(DataSet dataSet)
{
    foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
     {   if (table.Rows.Count != 0) return false; }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you try to take information from the DB, with something like:

```
If ds.tables("MyTable").rowsCount > 0 then
     // Do the stuff
Else
     // There is no information on the table
End If
```